# Extern compile error with SDL_Surface

Tags: sdl, extern, compiler-errors

I've been getting a compile error in `Code::Block` for an `SDL_Surface` variable. Strangely enough, this is the first time I have received this kind of error, as I have used this line of code previously and it has worked fine.

One (of several with the same problem) sample line of code that causes this problem is:

```
extern SDL_Surface *screen;
```

The resulting error is this:

```
expected init-declarator before "extern"|
expected `,' or `;' before "extern"|

||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

I tried to understand the error, but I can not tell what it is. Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's a wild guess since I don't have much to work with. Do you have all the headers required for `SDL_Surface` before that `extern`?

Comment: Ya, the header file is #include "SDL.h" and I've used this line on my previous project

Comment: @Anoymonous: You've mentioned multiple problems. If this is not the first error that you've hit, try fixing the ones before this one.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the definition of `SDL_Surface`.  Make sure to `#include` the proper header file in which `SDL_Surface` is defined.  Alternatively, if you're not actually using the `screen` variable (i.e. you're not accessing any of its fields), you can declare it using an *incomplete type* as so:

```
extern struct SDL_Surface *screen;
```